# Can/Should a web application connect to a secure web service on the same server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, security

I have a web application and web service on the same server.  Both are .NET.  For the web service I setup 2 versions.  One is secure and uses https.  The other is not. Applications not on the server use the secure instance and it works fine.  I can use the unsecure instance (http) for the web application that is on the same server and it works fine.

My question: Can or should you use a secure version of a web service when you are connecting to it from the same server?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Web service binding:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPaging" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" sendTimeout="00:25:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="200000000" maxStringContentLength="200000000" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
```

The endpoint defined:

```
<endpoint address="https://<server_name>/PagingServiceSecure/PagingService.Paging.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IPaging" contract="PagingService.IPaging" name="WSHttpBinding_IPaging">
```

When trying to connect to the secure web service that is on a server from my local machine, I get the error:
**Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) authentication failed. 
The server may not be running in an account with identity 'host/'. 
If the server is running in a service account (Network Service for example), 
specify the account's ServicePrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for the server.**

I don't understand the error.  I have a certificate on the server. Shouldn't the check be that the connection is using the correct domain and then allow access to the web service?

Comment: do you see performance impact if you use HTTPS for local traffic?

Comment: I could not connect the web application to the secure version of the web service.  Secondly we have not gone live with this application yet.  I was wondering the reason I could not connect to the secure service is because it cannot check the certificate on itself.

Comment: I don't know about performance.  I can't connect.